# High UDP communication latency because of audio rendering (Windows, C++)

Tags: windows, audio, network-programming, udp, latency

I am trying to communicate  with an external robot at 1 kHz using UDP protocol with WinSocket library. I am using Windows 10 Pro Version 21H2. In the hardware side, I use a pc with intel core i9 10900X 32 GB RAM and Intel I219.

At a certain point it work pretty well, I did measure the time spent for the communication (both sending and receiving the packets sequentially takes between 200 microseconds and 500 microseconds), and I did also measure using wireshark the number of packets exchanged (1000 packets sent per second and 1000 packets received per second too). The throughput sending is 2 Mbps and receiving is 3Mbps.

The issue start when any audio is rendered (even the sound happening when changing the volume on windows), this lead to a noticeable latency (about 10 to 15 milliseconds).
When I stop the Windows Audio Service, this solves the issue but in our application, we need to render a sound permanently.

[graph : round trip time and frequency vs index of udp query, using NIC PCI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-D-3vfc2lIJ7kkFfTRwe0fLevppYX1_b/view?usp=sharing)

A temporary solution was to use a USB/Ethernet adapter instead of NICs. Using this type of device we have no latency but we already experienced in the past some issues related to drops of performance due to thermal throttling.

[graph : round trip time and frequency vs index of udp query, using USB/Ethernet adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyUrM.gif)

I also did try to reduce the audio process priority, no difference. I also tried to set the affinity mask of the audio service in different threads than my application, no difference neither.

My questions : is there a way to increase the audio latency in order to prioritize the udp communication or to reduce the latency of the udp communication to meet our need of 1 kHz frequency.

Comment: What kind of NIC are you using? A good PCI NIC should easily outperform an USB/Ethernet dongle. It is probably a driver problem. How is the robot connected? Copper Ethernet cable?

Comment: I did try many NICs intel I219 chipset (integrated in the motherboard) intel gigabyte on PCI, intel Killer, and two realtek. All those NICs outperform when there is no audio sound rendered by windows, but once I play any kind of sound, the USB keeps working as it is, but all NICs on PCI have a noticeable latency. There are two factors playing here : latency and throughput. Maybe the throughput can be higher using PCI interfaces, but in my case I am more concerned by the latency induced by the audio rendering

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that the pc and the robot are actually connected using a copper ethernet cable, no router in between.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the latency issue by using TCP/IP pings? Try eventually PsPing from Microsoft.

Comment: this would be not easy to do since the latency is no permanent.

Comment: Can you try another driver / audio chip? Maybe the audio driver is locking something. Audio drivers can be very cheeky since they are optimized for low latency. I don't think it is the Windows Audio Service itself. Does heavy disk I/O produce the same effect?

Comment: I already did : I updated the audio driver, no changes. I also downloaded the latest driver from realtek, no changes neither. It looks like that Windows intended to accept such behavior by giving more priority to the audio rendering, [Link documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/low-latency-audio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to the [Receive Side Throttle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/receive-side-throttle-in-ndis-6-20) feature some NICs support.

In order to fix it, you need to set the register variable
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile\NetworkThrottlingIndex` to `0xffffffff` and reboot windows.

This registry key is private and internal to Windows OS, it is not supposed to be used publicly and it's not officially supported by Microsoft.